# Groovy: Node.replaceNode with Node?

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

Suppose I have a node I'd like to replace with `replaceNode`, however, I don't want to use a `Builder` to do it - or rather, I already have the node with which to replace it:

```
replacement = new XmlParser.parse('input.xml')
root.depthFirst().replaceme.each { it ->
  it.replaceNode { node ->
    // This is what I can't figure out
  }
}
```

I've tried lots of different iterations, but can't seem to work it out.  If I just return text in that segment, it replaces the node with an empty node.

For example, if my input file is this:
    
      This should get replaced

And I have a replacement like this:
    This will replace the *Original*

I'd like to do something like:

```
top = new XmlParser().parseFile('input.xml')
top.middle.each { it ->
  it.replaceNode { node ->
    new XmlParser().parseFile('replacement.xml')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind switching to XmlSlurper() the following should work:

```
def top = new XmlSlurper().parse('input.xml')
top.middle.each { node ->
    node.replaceNode {
        mkp.yield(new XmlSlurper().parse('replacement.xml')) 
    }   
}
```

Which will replace all middle nodes with the contents of replacement.xml

Comment: Yup.  That did the trick.  Took a little more finagling because I'm using namespaces and strangely findAll wasn't working with them even though I declared them - had to use it.name() and it.namespaceURI for the comparison, but it all worked out.