# Replace XML Node with another instance of Node

Tags: xml, groovy

I use groovy to parse a XML file using [`XmlParser`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html). Using the dot notation I can receive the desired node as [`Node`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html) instances.

For my use case a Node is cloned, edited and will replace the original node once the editing is over.

The Node Object has a [`replaceNode`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html#replaceNode(groovy.lang.Closure)) implemented, which expects a closure, with this documentation:

> Replaces the current node with nodes defined using builder-style
>   notation via a Closure.
>
> @param c A Closure defining the new nodes using builder-style
>   notation.

### My question is, how can I replace one Node instance against another instace of Node?

This is what I do right now, which of course is not working:

```
Node referenceNode
Node editedNode
referenceNode.replaceNode {
    editedNode
}
```

As the `plus()` method also excpects the same syntax, this is a bit of a struggle for me.

Here is a related question with was solved using XmlSlurper, which I don't want to do: [Groovy: Node.replaceNode with Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265048/groovy-node-replacenode-with-node)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `replaceNode` with the node you want to replace it with:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xml = '''
<root>
    <user><name>a</name></user>
    <user><name>b</name></user>
    <user><name>c</name></user>    
</root>'''

parser = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

Node newNode = parser.user[2].clone()
newNode.@something = 'woo'
parser.user[1].replaceNode(newNode)

println XmlUtil.serialize(parser)
```

That prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <user>
    <name>a</name>
  </user>
  <user something="woo">
    <name>c</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>c</name>
  </user>
</root>
```

Comment: I actually feel stupid for not having tried this ;) thank you very much for your reply. I will test this tomorrow and give you a check as feedback :) thanks again!

Comment: No worries :-)  Hope I helped!

Comment: sadly this throw an exception for me `No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.replaceNode() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.Node) values: [user[attributes={something=woo}; value=[name[attributes={}; value=[c]]]]] Possible solutions: replaceNode(groovy.lang.Closure)` Maybe the problem is my old grails version of 2.3.11

Comment: Odd... I'll look when http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html#replaceNode(groovy.util.Node) was added...

Comment: Thank you for your time. You are absolutely right. I will mark this answer as correct, as it is corrected in a newer version of groovy. For now i solved  my problem by implementing a  private helper method in my service that does mainly this: 

`replaced.children().toArray().each {
            replaced.remove(it)
        }

        node.children().each {
            replaced.append(it)
        }`

and alters the attributes also.