# Groovy Change xml node name for children node

Tags: groovy

Need help on Groovy script to changing all feature tags to features

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<featureList>
  <feature>
   </feature>
<feature>
   </feature>
<feature>
   </feature>
<feature>`
   </feature>

</featureList>
```

Comment: Missed to mention .. feature tag to features

Comment: Please show what you have tried to do yourself - research and/or code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy: Node.replaceNode with Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265048/groovy-node-replacenode-with-node)